# Fast integer power of nine

Tags: math, optimization, mathematical-optimization, number-theory, exponentiation

I need to calculate 9^n where n is a natural number. I used binary exponentiation, but addition chain is not optimal. Also there exists [an optimal solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation), but it's proven to be NP-complete and is very hard to calculate. I cannot use lookup table in my task. Also this algorithm still doesn't use the fact that i know the basis. Maybe there are some papers in number theory, or you can suggest a better solution?

Comment: It sounds like there’s some surrounding context here that we don’t have. Are you trying to minimize the total number of arithmetic operations performed? Are there any other constraints we should know of?

Comment: Actually, i try to optimize 9^n + 9^(n-1) + ... 9^1 series. These can be written as sum of geometrical progression or, simplified, as -9/8 * (1 - 9^n).

Comment: How big is n? How do you plan to represent the result?

Comment: n is about 10^9...2^64 - 1
result is a text file with resulting number

Comment: 9^n in that case would be astonishingly huge - it’ll have roughly n digits, and if n = 2^64 that won’t fit on any hard disk I know of. Can you elaborate on what you’re trying to do and why?

Comment: Ok, i was a bit incorrect with 2^64 - i tried to fit the number in int64. Assume that n is big and i can't use any sort of caching or approximation. The problem isn't practical at all. It's just a dispute about fastest way to calculate this power. Pure theory. Thatswhy i'm interested in O-notation, not the real results

Comment: @JoshuaJakowlew without seeing your implementation, measured runtimes , and environment details how can we know we have better or worse solution ? Post an MCVE with sample input and output that is already slow for you ... language and programing techniques can make a huge difference (while the algo is the same) Also how big the `n` is because just stating its big is not enough we need to know if its limited or arbitrary size ... etc ...

Comment: The fastest way to compute 9\**n is to simply store it using an appropriate representation, say in a tuple (x, y) that represents x\**y. So 9\**n = (9,n), an O(1) solution.